# ec2-import-instance doesn't work on Windows

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm trying to import a vmdk image using `ec2-import-instance` command but it returns below error:

> usage: aws [options]   [parameters] aws: error:
>   argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:
>
> autoscaling                              | cloudformation cloudfront
>   | cloudhsm cloudsearch                              |
>   cloudsearchdomain etc..

My command is here:

```
aws ec2-import-instance "C:\AWS-TEST-VM\aws-test-vm-01\aws-test-vm-01-disk1.vmdk" -f vmdk -t m1.small -a x86_64 -b bucket_name -o Access Key –w Secret+Access+Key -p Linux --ignore-region-affinity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are mixing up two different command-line interfaces.

The 'older-style' commands have hyphenated words, eg:

```
ec2-import-instance -t instance_type [-g group] -f file_format -a architecture [-p platform_name] -b s3_bucket_name ...
```

The newer [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) uses the syntax of `aws <service> <command> <parameters>`, for example:

```
aws ec2 import-image [--description <value>] [--disk-containers <value>] [--license-type <value>] ...
```

See:

- Old-Style: [ec2-import-instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-ImportInstance.html)
- New-Style: [import-image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/import-image.html)

Comment: @john : Do boto or boto3 have some api for import-image?

Comment: The AWS CLI uses boto, so it is definitely in there! This seems to be the one for boto3: https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.import_image